# Rotate Leaflet markers tooltip text

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, leaflet

I have some JSON with data that should be shown on the map.

```
var shapesCoordinates = '[{"shapeId": 1,"coordinates": [-1500,500],"text": "bla bla", "rotation": 20},{"shapeId": 2,"coordinates": [-1800,800],"text": "idemooooo", "rotation": 60}]';
var shapess = JSON.parse(shapesCoordinates);

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < shapess.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker(shapess[i]['coordinates'], {
        opacity: 0.01
    }).bindTooltip(shapess[i]['text'],
        {
            permanent: true,
            className: "shapesText",
            offset: [0, 0],
            direction: "center"
        }
    ).openTooltip().addTo(mymap);

    markers[shapess[i]['shapeId']] = marker;
}
```

I tried to rotate text with CSS but there is some issue.

```
     .leaflet-tooltip {
            box-shadow: none;
            /** 
              This rotates text but break marker position
               set all markers on same (default) position
            */
            transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
        }

    .shapesText {
        position: absolute;
        /**
          This has no impact on text
        */
        transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
        font-size:14px;
        background: none;
        border: none
    }
```

I figure out why this issue happens.

generated HTML code has **`transform: translate3d()`** and when I use **transform: rotate()`** it override element reposition. How can I use both property values together? In other words, how can I add rotation without overriding translate3d

Is there is some Leaflet's way to set different rotation to each marker if it is needed?

I am just using Leaflet to show a custom non-geographic map and there is needs to show sometimes text which will follow some shapes borders.

This is generated HTML code

```
<div class="leaflet-tooltip shapesText leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-tooltip-center" style="opacity: 0.9; transform: translate3d(385px, -32px, 0px);">bla bla</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML for one of the tooltips?

Comment: There is no HTML! Marker tooltip is generated dynamically with bindTooltip() method.

Comment: Any `bindTooltip()` doesn't generate any HTML for the DOM, no?

Comment: I had updated question, with generated HTML content.

Comment: So, I guess, that transform: rotate(...), override transform: translate3d(...)

Comment: I can't find a way to make `transform: rotate(45deg)` not override the 3d transformation, nor can I find an explanation for it. The closest I got was playing with pseudos: https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/LeRdPP?editors=1100 But this relies on updating your JS to add your tooltip text as a data-attribute so the CSS can pick it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782930/add-data-attribute-to-leaflet-js-marker-element

Comment: I had solved this issue, can you check solution? I put this as the answer. I am not sure if there is maybe a bug in CSS 3 maybe?

Comment: Upstream pull request: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/7140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to play a game with current tooltip content.

```
var shapess = JSON.parse(shapesCoordinates);

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < shapess.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker(shapess[i]['coordinates'], {
        opacity: 0.01
    }).bindTooltip(shapess[i]['text'],
        {
            permanent: true,
            className: "shapesText" + i,
            offset: [0, 0],
            direction: "center"
        }
    ).openTooltip().addTo(mymap);
```

I needed to access marker tooltip and change its HTML code in order to replace older **`transform`** property with current **`translate3d`** value and add dummy **`rotate`** value. 
Dummy in reason that added rotation does not work.

```
    if (shapess[i]["rotation"]) {
        var content = marker['_tooltip']['_container'];
        var style = $(content).attr('style');
        var transformProperty = style.substring(style.indexOf('transform'));
        var transformRotationProperty = transformProperty.replace(';', ' rotation(' + shapess[i]["rotation"] + 'deg);');
        var changedContent = content.outerHTML.replace(transformProperty, transformRotationProperty);

        marker['_tooltip'].setContent(changedContent);
        $('.shapesText' + i).css({'transform': 'rotate(' + shapess[i]["rotation"] + 'deg)'});
    }
    markers[shapess[i]['shapeId']] = marker;

}
```

After new content is added to tooltip I can access tooltip class and change **`transform`** property by adding only **`rotate`** value.
It will keep old **`translate`** value without overriding.

I am not sure if it is a bug or what can be a problem, but if I add only **`rotate`** without **`translate3d`** old value will be overridden.

But, if old **`transform`** has both **`translate3d`** and **`rotate`**
using CSS transform with only rotate will not override old **`translate3d`**

Comment: Sorry, it was early for me this morning! It's not a bug in CSS3. I've realized transforms are a kind of a shorthand and the values (rotate, translate etc.) must be combined. You're on the right lines, basically copy the current position and then inject your rotation into the inline transform. https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/OzRBeW?editors=0011