# Dynamic change font-size in Leaflet marker tooltip text on zoom change

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I show some text on map, I did this by this example

[Rotate Lealfet markers tooltip text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938963/rotate-lealfet-markers-tooltip-text)

I need to see smaller text if zoom out and text should be larger when I zoom in.

```
mymap.on('zoomend', function () {
    var zoomLevel = mymap.getZoom();
    var tooltip = $('.leaflet-tooltip');

    switch (zoomLevel) {
        case -2:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 7);
            break;
        case -1:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 10);
            break;
        case 0:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 12);
            break;
        case 1:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 14);
            break;
        case 2:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 16);
            break;
        case 3:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 18);
            break;
        default:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 14);
    }
}
```

I guess this is not by the book solution and I want to ask for a better way for changing font size dynamically to follow map size on zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: Your current solution seems good to me. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: There is a time gap between zoom before font size is changed :/

Comment: Then change it to `zoomstart`?

Comment: Good point! There are known data for next zoom level on `zoomstart` or there is data only for direction where zoom goes?

Comment: Check the event properties. I have no experience with leaflet.

Comment: You were right, zoomstart fix the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I just change event from **`zoomend`** to **`zoomstart`** and there is no more big time gap between zooming and font changing.

```
mymap.on('zoomstart', function () {
    var zoomLevel = mymap.getZoom();
    var tooltip = $('.leaflet-tooltip');

    switch (zoomLevel) {
        case -2:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 7);
            break;
        case -1:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 10);
            break;
        case 0:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 12);
            break;
        case 1:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 14);
            break;
        case 2:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 16);
            break;
        case 3:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 18);
            break;
        default:
            tooltip.css('font-size', 14);
    }
});
```